# Swift actor: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000

Tags: ios, swift, swift-concurrency

I am trying to perform an API call on a list of `Draft` which are queued< (1 call by `Draft`).

For this I have created a `DraftQueue`:

```
actor DraftQueue {
    private var taskQueue = [String: Task<Void, Never>]()

    func cleanQueueElement(uuid: String) {
        taskQueue[uuid]?.cancel()
        taskQueue[uuid] = nil
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a function supposed to save a `Draft` online:

```
private func saveDraft(draft: Draft, mailboxManager: MailboxManager) async {
    await draftQueue.cleanQueueElement(uuid: draft.localUUID)
    await mailboxManager.save(draft: draft)
}
```

The function `saveDraft` is called in another function that gets all the `Draft` that needs to be saved and saves them:

```
public func syncDraft(mailboxManager: MailboxManager) {
    Task {
        let drafts = await mailboxManager.draftWithPendingAction()
        for draft in drafts {
            Task {
                await self.saveDraft(draft: draft, mailboxManager: mailboxManager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that sometimes I get this error in the function `cleanQueueElement`.

`-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000`

Comment: try getting rid of the inner `Task` it kind of defeats the purpose of `async await`

Comment: I Already tried that

Comment: There isn't enough code to reproduce the issue but my guess is that this is a timing issue. That `taskQueue` variable seems suspicious and depending on the setup the outer task in the sync function is also ignoring the concurrent benefits.

Comment: What's weird is if the debugger isn't connected, the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Have you tried using the diagnostic tools outlined in [Diagnosing memory, thread, and crash issues early](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/) (as well as the “Memory Management” settings on the “Diagnostics” tab in your scheme settings)? Also, I’d try setting the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Complete”.

Comment: `taskQueue[uuid] = nil` looks wrong.  especially since the value `Task<Void,Never>` is not an optional.  Are you sure you don't want `taskQueue.removeValue(forKey: uuid)`

Comment: @ScottThompson - `dictionary[key] = nil` is an acceptable way to remove an entry from a dictionary. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/) says, “If you assign `nil` to an existing key, the key and its associated value are removed.”